# Is there a better way to write this react code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code such as this

```js
export default function Landing(props) {
    return props.arr.map((a, i) => {
        if (a.whatEver === "Whatever") {
            return (
                <p key={i}>whatever</p>
            )
        } else if (a.whichEver === "Whichever") {
            return (
                <p key={i}>whichever</p>
            )
        } else if (a.another === "Another") {
            return (
                <p key={i}>another</p>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <p key={i}>whoever</p>
            )
        }
    })
}
```

This is assuming arr is an array of objects.

This code works for me but is there a better way of presenting this? thanks

Comment: You could save a little code with something like `<p key={i}>{displayText(a)}<p>` and put the logic in displayText. Or you could do `<p key={i}>{a.whatEver === "Whatever" ? 'whatever' : a.whichEver === "Whichever" ? 'whichever : ...}<p>`

Comment: What confuses me slighly is that each property name is different. Like `a.whatever` and `a.whichever`. It would make more sense if the property names where all the same, just different values. Then you could just make an object like `const a = { key: value };` and use `if(a.hasOwnProperty(key)){ return a.key; }`

Comment: @icecub you don't seem to have read my question properly, I mentioned assuming arr is an array of objects which I am mapping through

Comment: I did read that. And [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used to create a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. All you do is just check if a key in the object has a certain value and return something based on it. I'm not saying your method is wrong or anything. It's not. Just that there are a bunch of different ways to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```js
export default function Landing(props) {
    return props.arr.map((a, i) => {
        if (a.whatEver === "Whatever")
            return <p key={i}>whatever</p>;
        if (a.whichEver === "WhichEver")
            return <p key={i}>whichEver</p>;
        if (a.another === "Another")
            return <p key={i}>another</p>;
        return <p key={i}>whoever</p>;
    })
}
```

or if there's only one key you need to check in the array, use `switch...case` (my personal favorite):

```js
export default function Landing(props) {
    return props.arr.map((a, i) => {
        switch (a.importantKey) {
            case "Whatever":
                return <p key={i}>whatever</p>;
            case "WhichEver":
                return <p key={i}>whichEver</p>;
            case "Another":
                return <p key={i}>another</p>;
            default: return <p key={i}>whoever</p>;
        }
    })
}
```